# where is $table->stamps() documented and how do you roll it back?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

So at my job we have a project using https://github.com/WildSideUK/Laravel-Userstamps . In existant migrations there's `$table->stamps();` which creates `created_at`, `deleted_at`, `created_by`, etc.

This method is not documented at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations so I'm assuming that that's part of https://github.com/WildSideUK/Laravel-Userstamps but even that doesn't have any documentation on `$table->stamps();`, let alone how to undo it when rolling back.

I did `grep -r "n stamps" .` in the projects root directory and didn't find anything, but with Laravel's penchant for magic methods that doesn't surprise me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$table->stamps()` is not a standard Laravel schema builder method. 
But `$table->timestamps()` is, and it is the method responsible for creating the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, while `deleted_at` is added with `$table->softDeletes()`.

To revert these you can use respectively `$table->dropTimestamps()` and `$table->dropSoftDeletes()`.